# ESP: Auto login/accept message by OS with redirect to page like public WIFI portals access points

Tags: c++, arduino-esp8266, wifi, access-point

**Example:**

I do not know how you call this feature so I try to explain it. For example when you connect your phone to a public WiFi hotspot/access point, you receive a message from OS that it is required to accept terms/conditions or you need to logon to be able to use the connection. When you click onto this message it opens the/a browser and launch a landing page.

How do they do this? Is this a https feature?

---

**Update:**(1)

It is called a Captive Portal:

The captive portal technique forces an HTTP client on a network to see a special web page (usually for authentication purposes) before using the Internet normally. A captive portal turns a Web browser into an authentication device. This is done by intercepting most packets, regardless of address or port, until the user opens a browser and tries to access the web. At that time the browser is redirected to a web page which may require authentication and/or payment, or simply display an acceptable use policy and require the user to agree. Captive portals are used at many Wi-Fi hotspots, and can be used to control wired access (e.g. apartment houses, hotel rooms, business centers, "open" Ethernet jacks) as well.

---

**Situation:**

I want to do the same with an ESP (ESP32/ESP8266) because I develop a device that can be configurated via WiFi. It would be very user friendly when the user connect to the device and doesn't have to open a browser first, type in an IP-address etc. Just a message, user can click on it and a main page will be launched.

In AP mode, I have turned on DNS and redirect everything to the main page however is not the best solution (also sometimes doesn't work). To give you some idea what I am doing, here some code, a part of my library:

```
bool suStartAccessPointNetwork( String  sSSIDNetworkName, String   sSSIDPassword,
                                IPAddress sStaticIpAddress,
                                uint16_t iDnsPort = 0,
                                uint8_t iTries = 20, 
                                uint16_t iDelay = 500 
                              )
{ 
  WiFi.disconnect();
  suSetNetworkAccessPointMode();
  delay( 1000 );
  WiFi.softAPConfig( sStaticIpAddress,
                       sStaticIpAddress,
                       IPAddress( 255, 255, 255, 0 )
                     ); 

  SU_WIFI_AP_ESTABLISHED = WiFi.softAP( sSSIDNetworkName.c_str(), sSSIDPassword.c_str() );

  if( iDnsPort > 0 )
  {
       static SUDNSServer* pDnsServer = NULLPTR;

       if( !pDnsServer )
        { pDnsServer = new SUDNSServer(); }

       // modify TTL, default is 60 seconds
       pDnsServer->setTTL(60);

       // set which return code will be used for all other domains (e.g. sending
       // ServerFailure instead of NonExistentDomain will reduce number of queries
       // sent by clients)
       // default is DNSReplyCode::NonExistentDomain
       pDnsServer->setErrorReplyCode( DNSReplyCode::NoError );
       pDnsServer->start( iDnsPort, 
                        //SCDMS_MDNS_ACCESS_NAME, 
                        "*", 
                        sStaticIpAddress
                       );

       Serial.print("DNS server started at " );
       Serial.println( sStaticIpAddress ); 

       suSetDnsServer( pDnsServer );
  } 


  Serial.print("[AP]:");

  bool bConnected = false;

  if( iTries == 0 )
   { ++iTries; } 

   // Try to connect, give WiFi 10 seconds to launch a network as access point.
  while( !(bConnected = suIsNetworkEstablished()) && (iTries--) )
  {
      Serial.print('.');
      //Serial.print(WiFi.status());
      delay(500);
  }

  if( bConnected )
   { SU_WIFI_AP_ESTABLISHED = bConnected; }

  Serial.println( bConnected?" ((o))":" o?" );


  return bConnected;
}
```

---

**Question:**

How can I implement such feature like discribed in the example above? Any ideas? Is it possible anyway?

### --------------------

**Update 2:**

@gre_gor came up with the same examples I also found after knowing the name of the service (see also update 1). Implement the Url paths etc like in the example, doesn't work as described above. Okay, tried the full example, same result, no OS popup/message, no redirection. Entering the IP-adress at the browser, this is working however the same I already had.

*One of the extended demo's i have tried:*

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

/*
   This example serves a "hello world" on a WLAN and a SoftAP at the same time.
   The SoftAP allow you to configure WLAN parameters at run time. They are not setup in the sketch but saved on EEPROM.
   Connect your computer or cell phone to wifi network ESP_ap with password 12345678. A popup may appear and it allow you to go to WLAN config. If it does not then navigate to http://192.168.4.1/wifi and config it there.
   Then wait for the module to connect to your wifi and take note of the WLAN IP it got. Then you can disconnect from ESP_ap and return to your regular WLAN.
   Now the ESP8266 is in your network. You can reach it through http://192.168.x.x/ (the IP you took note of) or maybe at http://esp8266.local too.
   This is a captive portal because through the softAP it will redirect any http request to http://192.168.4.1/
*/

/* Set these to your desired softAP credentials. They are not configurable at runtime */
#ifndef APSSID
#define APSSID "ESP_ap"
#define APPSK  "12345678"
#endif

const char *softAP_ssid = APSSID;
const char *softAP_password = APPSK;

/* hostname for mDNS. Should work at least on windows. Try http://esp8266.local */
const char *myHostname = "esp8266";

/* Don't set this wifi credentials. They are configurated at runtime and stored on EEPROM */
char ssid[32] = "";
char password[32] = "";

// DNS server
const byte DNS_PORT = 53;
DNSServer dnsServer;

// Web server
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

/* Soft AP network parameters */
IPAddress apIP(192, 168, 4, 1);
IPAddress netMsk(255, 255, 255, 0);


/** Should I connect to WLAN asap? */
boolean connect;

/** Last time I tried to connect to WLAN */
unsigned long lastConnectTry = 0;

/** Current WLAN status */
unsigned int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

/** Is this an IP? */
boolean isIp(String str) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    int c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c != '.' && (c < '0' || c > '9')) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

/** IP to String? */
String toStringIp(IPAddress ip) {
  String res = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    res += String((ip >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF) + ".";
  }
  res += String(((ip >> 8 * 3)) & 0xFF);
  return res;
}

/** Load WLAN credentials from EEPROM */
void loadCredentials() {
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  EEPROM.get(0, ssid);
  EEPROM.get(0 + sizeof(ssid), password);
  char ok[2 + 1];
  EEPROM.get(0 + sizeof(ssid) + sizeof(password), ok);
  EEPROM.end();
  if (String(ok) != String("OK")) {
    ssid[0] = 0;
    password[0] = 0;
  }
  Serial.println("Recovered credentials:");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.println(strlen(password) > 0 ? "********" : "<no password>");
}

/** Store WLAN credentials to EEPROM */
void saveCredentials() {
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  EEPROM.put(0, ssid);
  EEPROM.put(0 + sizeof(ssid), password);
  char ok[2 + 1] = "OK";
  EEPROM.put(0 + sizeof(ssid) + sizeof(password), ok);
  EEPROM.commit();
  EEPROM.end();
}

/** Handle root or redirect to captive portal */
void handleRoot() {
  if (captivePortal()) { // If caprive portal redirect instead of displaying the page.
    return;
  }
  server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  server.sendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  server.sendHeader("Expires", "-1");

  String Page;
  Page += F(
            "<html><head></head><body>"
            "<h1>HELLO WORLD!!</h1>");
  if (server.client().localIP() == apIP) {
    Page += String(F("<p>You are connected through the soft AP: ")) + softAP_ssid + F("</p>");
  } else {
    Page += String(F("<p>You are connected through the wifi network: ")) + ssid + F("</p>");
  }
  Page += F(
            "<p>You may want to <a href='/wifi'>config the wifi connection</a>.</p>"
            "</body></html>");

  server.send(200, "text/html", Page);
}

/** Redirect to captive portal if we got a request for another domain. Return true in that case so the page handler do not try to handle the request again. */
boolean captivePortal() {
  if (!isIp(server.hostHeader()) && server.hostHeader() != (String(myHostname) + ".local")) {
    Serial.println("Request redirected to captive portal");
    server.sendHeader("Location", String("http://") + toStringIp(server.client().localIP()), true);
    server.send(302, "text/plain", "");   // Empty content inhibits Content-length header so we have to close the socket ourselves.
    server.client().stop(); // Stop is needed because we sent no content length
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

/** Wifi config page handler */
void handleWifi() {
  server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  server.sendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  server.sendHeader("Expires", "-1");

  String Page;
  Page += F(
            "<html><head></head><body>"
            "<h1>Wifi config</h1>");
  if (server.client().localIP() == apIP) {
    Page += String(F("<p>You are connected through the soft AP: ")) + softAP_ssid + F("</p>");
  } else {
    Page += String(F("<p>You are connected through the wifi network: ")) + ssid + F("</p>");
  }
  Page +=
    String(F(
             "\r\n<br />"
             "<table><tr><th align='left'>SoftAP config</th></tr>"
             "<tr><td>SSID ")) +
    String(softAP_ssid) +
    F("</td></tr>"
      "<tr><td>IP ") +
    toStringIp(WiFi.softAPIP()) +
    F("</td></tr>"
      "</table>"
      "\r\n<br />"
      "<table><tr><th align='left'>WLAN config</th></tr>"
      "<tr><td>SSID ") +
    String(ssid) +
    F("</td></tr>"
      "<tr><td>IP ") +
    toStringIp(WiFi.localIP()) +
    F("</td></tr>"
      "</table>"
      "\r\n<br />"
      "<table><tr><th align='left'>WLAN list (refresh if any missing)</th></tr>");
  Serial.println("scan start");
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("scan done");
  if (n > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      Page += String(F("\r\n<tr><td>SSID ")) + WiFi.SSID(i) + ((WiFi.encryptionType(i) == ENC_TYPE_NONE) ? F(" ") : F(" *")) + F(" (") + WiFi.RSSI(i) + F(")</td></tr>");
    }
  } else {
    Page += F("<tr><td>No WLAN found</td></tr>");
  }
  Page += F(
            "</table>"
            "\r\n<br /><form method='POST' action='wifisave'><h4>Connect to network:</h4>"
            "<input type='text' placeholder='network' name='n'/>"
            "<br /><input type='password' placeholder='password' name='p'/>"
            "<br /><input type='submit' value='Connect/Disconnect'/></form>"
            "<p>You may want to <a href='/'>return to the home page</a>.</p>"
            "</body></html>");
  server.send(200, "text/html", Page);
  server.client().stop(); // Stop is needed because we sent no content length
}

/** Handle the WLAN save form and redirect to WLAN config page again */
void handleWifiSave() {
  Serial.println("wifi save");
  server.arg("n").toCharArray(ssid, sizeof(ssid) - 1);
  server.arg("p").toCharArray(password, sizeof(password) - 1);
  server.sendHeader("Location", "wifi", true);
  server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  server.sendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  server.sendHeader("Expires", "-1");
  server.send(302, "text/plain", "");    // Empty content inhibits Content-length header so we have to close the socket ourselves.
  server.client().stop(); // Stop is needed because we sent no content length
  saveCredentials();
  connect = strlen(ssid) > 0; // Request WLAN connect with new credentials if there is a SSID
}

void handleNotFound() {
  if (captivePortal()) { // If caprive portal redirect instead of displaying the error page.
    return;
  }
  String message = F("File Not Found\n\n");
  message += F("URI: ");
  message += server.uri();
  message += F("\nMethod: ");
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += F("\nArguments: ");
  message += server.args();
  message += F("\n");

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
    message += String(F(" ")) + server.argName(i) + F(": ") + server.arg(i) + F("\n");
  }
  server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  server.sendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  server.sendHeader("Expires", "-1");
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
}

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Configuring access point...");
  /* You can remove the password parameter if you want the AP to be open. */
  WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, netMsk);
  WiFi.softAP(softAP_ssid, softAP_password);
  delay(500); // Without delay I've seen the IP address blank
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());

  /* Setup the DNS server redirecting all the domains to the apIP */
  dnsServer.setErrorReplyCode(DNSReplyCode::NoError);
  dnsServer.start(DNS_PORT, "*", apIP);

  /* Setup web pages: root, wifi config pages, SO captive portal detectors and not found. */
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.on("/wifi", handleWifi);
  server.on("/wifisave", handleWifiSave);
  server.on("/generate_204", handleRoot);  //Android captive portal. Maybe not needed. Might be handled by notFound handler.
  server.on("/fwlink", handleRoot);  //Microsoft captive portal. Maybe not needed. Might be handled by notFound handler.
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  server.begin(); // Web server start
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
  loadCredentials(); // Load WLAN credentials from network
  connect = strlen(ssid) > 0; // Request WLAN connect if there is a SSID
}

void connectWifi() {
  Serial.println("Connecting as wifi client...");
  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  int connRes = WiFi.waitForConnectResult();
  Serial.print("connRes: ");
  Serial.println(connRes);
}

void loop() {
  if (connect) {
    Serial.println("Connect requested");
    connect = false;
    connectWifi();
    lastConnectTry = millis();
  }
  {
    unsigned int s = WiFi.status();
    if (s == 0 && millis() > (lastConnectTry + 60000)) {
      /* If WLAN disconnected and idle try to connect */
      /* Don't set retry time too low as retry interfere the softAP operation */
      connect = true;
    }
    if (status != s) { // WLAN status change
      Serial.print("Status: ");
      Serial.println(s);
      status = s;
      if (s == WL_CONNECTED) {
        /* Just connected to WLAN */
        Serial.println("");
        Serial.print("Connected to ");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        Serial.print("IP address: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

        // Setup MDNS responder
        if (!MDNS.begin(myHostname)) {
          Serial.println("Error setting up MDNS responder!");
        } else {
          Serial.println("mDNS responder started");
          // Add service to MDNS-SD
          MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);
        }
      } else if (s == WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL) {
        WiFi.disconnect();
      }
    }
    if (s == WL_CONNECTED) {
      MDNS.update();
    }
  }
  // Do work:
  //DNS
  dnsServer.processNextRequest();
  //HTTP
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: "How do I do X?" questions are too broad. And there are [existing examples how to do it on an ESP8266](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/DNSServer/examples). There is also [an existing library for configuration that uses a captive portal](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager).

Comment: @gre_gor, the same I am just looking at. Before posting this question I didn't even know the name of this feature (see also update question). So be kind please.

Comment: If my links answered your question, you should just delete the question, since it's too broad. Unless you have a more specific question about your code.

Comment: Also found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal . Gives me more insight than anything else.

Comment: @gre_gor : Too broad? I don't agree. Because there is no explanation at all how it acactly must be implemented and why. Just an example is not enough, need some background info to understand it.

Comment: @gre_gor: Tried both demos, nope, not the same behaviour like the example description. It does the same I already had. No popup, nothing, also redirect doesn't work either. One of the examples In the Serial console replies that request is redirected to captive portal however browser say "Cannot connect". Tried several devices, it doesn't work. However enter the IP-address it specifies, this is working. But yeah, the same I already had.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found this: https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=15993

This post of eduperez:

---

*"Android devices have the Google DNSs hard-coded, they will **always use 8.8.8.8** and 8.8.4.4, despite what the DHPC server might tell them to use. You need to configure your gateway to redirect all outgoing traffic to port 53 to your DNS."*

---

That gives the idea, use **8.8.8.8 as IP-address and as DNS-server address**. 
Tada! Works like a charm!

So this sketch will work:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

/*
   This example serves a "hello world" on a WLAN and a SoftAP at the same time.
   The SoftAP allow you to configure WLAN parameters at run time. They are not setup in the sketch but saved on EEPROM.
   Connect your computer or cell phone to wifi network ESP_ap with password 12345678. A popup may appear and it allow you to go to WLAN config. If it does not then navigate to http://192.168.4.1/wifi and config it there.
   Then wait for the module to connect to your wifi and take note of the WLAN IP it got. Then you can disconnect from ESP_ap and return to your regular WLAN.
   Now the ESP8266 is in your network. You can reach it through http://192.168.x.x/ (the IP you took note of) or maybe at http://esp8266.local too.
   This is a captive portal because through the softAP it will redirect any http request to http://192.168.4.1/
*/

/* Set these to your desired softAP credentials. They are not configurable at runtime */
#ifndef APSSID
#define APSSID "TheGeekMan"
#define APPSK  "12345678"
#endif

const char *softAP_ssid = APSSID;
const char *softAP_password = APPSK;

/* hostname for mDNS. Should work at least on windows. Try http://esp8266.local */
const char *myHostname = "thegeekman";

/* Don't set this wifi credentials. They are configurated at runtime and stored on EEPROM */
char ssid[32] = "";
char password[32] = "";

// DNS server
const byte DNS_PORT = 53;
DNSServer dnsServer;

// Web server
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

/* Soft AP network parameters */
//IPAddress apIP(192, 168, 4, 1);
IPAddress apIP(8, 8, 8, 8);
IPAddress netMsk(255, 255, 255, 0);


/** Should I connect to WLAN asap? */
boolean connect;

/** Last time I tried to connect to WLAN */
unsigned long lastConnectTry = 0;

/** Current WLAN status */
unsigned int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

/** Is this an IP? */
boolean isIp(String str) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    int c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c != '.' && (c < '0' || c > '9')) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

/** IP to String? */
String toStringIp(IPAddress ip) {
  String res = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    res += String((ip >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF) + ".";
  }
  res += String(((ip >> 8 * 3)) & 0xFF);
  return res;
}

/** Load WLAN credentials from EEPROM */
void loadCredentials() {
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  EEPROM.get(0, ssid);
  EEPROM.get(0 + sizeof(ssid), password);
  char ok[2 + 1];
  EEPROM.get(0 + sizeof(ssid) + sizeof(password), ok);
  EEPROM.end();
  if (String(ok) != String("OK")) {
    ssid[0] = 0;
    password[0] = 0;
  }
  Serial.println("Recovered credentials:");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.println(strlen(password) > 0 ? "********" : "<no password>");
}

/** Store WLAN credentials to EEPROM */
void saveCredentials() {
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  EEPROM.put(0, ssid);
  EEPROM.put(0 + sizeof(ssid), password);
  char ok[2 + 1] = "OK";
  EEPROM.put(0 + sizeof(ssid) + sizeof(password), ok);
  EEPROM.commit();
  EEPROM.end();
}

/** Handle root or redirect to captive portal */
void handleRoot() {
  if (captivePortal()) { // If caprive portal redirect instead of displaying the page.
    return;
  }
  server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  server.sendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  server.sendHeader("Expires", "-1");

  String Page;
  Page += F(
            "<html><head></head><body>"
            "<h1>HELLO WORLD!!</h1>");
  if (server.client().localIP() == apIP) {
    Page += String(F("<p>You are connected through the soft AP: ")) + softAP_ssid + F("</p>");
  } else {
    Page += String(F("<p>You are connected through the wifi network: ")) + ssid + F("</p>");
  }
  Page += F(
            "<p>You may want to <a href='/wifi'>config the wifi connection</a>.</p>"
            "</body></html>");

  server.send(200, "text/html", Page);
}

/** Redirect to captive portal if we got a request for another domain. Return true in that case so the page handler do not try to handle the request again. */
boolean captivePortal() {
  if (!isIp(server.hostHeader()) && server.hostHeader() != (String(myHostname) + ".local")) {
    Serial.println("Request redirected to captive portal");
    server.sendHeader("Location", String("http://") + toStringIp(server.client().localIP()), true);
    server.send(302, "text/plain", "");   // Empty content inhibits Content-length header so we have to close the socket ourselves.
    server.client().stop(); // Stop is needed because we sent no content length
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

/** Wifi config page handler */
void handleWifi() {
  server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  server.sendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  server.sendHeader("Expires", "-1");

  String Page;
  Page += F(
            "<html><head></head><body>"
            "<h1>Wifi config</h1>");
  if (server.client().localIP() == apIP) {
    Page += String(F("<p>You are connected through the soft AP: ")) + softAP_ssid + F("</p>");
  } else {
    Page += String(F("<p>You are connected through the wifi network: ")) + ssid + F("</p>");
  }
  Page +=
    String(F(
             "\r\n<br />"
             "<table><tr><th align='left'>SoftAP config</th></tr>"
             "<tr><td>SSID ")) +
    String(softAP_ssid) +
    F("</td></tr>"
      "<tr><td>IP ") +
    toStringIp(WiFi.softAPIP()) +
    F("</td></tr>"
      "</table>"
      "\r\n<br />"
      "<table><tr><th align='left'>WLAN config</th></tr>"
      "<tr><td>SSID ") +
    String(ssid) +
    F("</td></tr>"
      "<tr><td>IP ") +
    toStringIp(WiFi.localIP()) +
    F("</td></tr>"
      "</table>"
      "\r\n<br />"
      "<table><tr><th align='left'>WLAN list (refresh if any missing)</th></tr>");
  Serial.println("scan start");
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("scan done");
  if (n > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      Page += String(F("\r\n<tr><td>SSID ")) + WiFi.SSID(i) + ((WiFi.encryptionType(i) == ENC_TYPE_NONE) ? F(" ") : F(" *")) + F(" (") + WiFi.RSSI(i) + F(")</td></tr>");
    }
  } else {
    Page += F("<tr><td>No WLAN found</td></tr>");
  }
  Page += F(
            "</table>"
            "\r\n<br /><form method='POST' action='wifisave'><h4>Connect to network:</h4>"
            "<input type='text' placeholder='network' name='n'/>"
            "<br /><input type='password' placeholder='password' name='p'/>"
            "<br /><input type='submit' value='Connect/Disconnect'/></form>"
            "<p>You may want to <a href='/'>return to the home page</a>.</p>"
            "</body></html>");
  server.send(200, "text/html", Page);
  server.client().stop(); // Stop is needed because we sent no content length
}

/** Handle the WLAN save form and redirect to WLAN config page again */
void handleWifiSave() {
  Serial.println("wifi save");
  server.arg("n").toCharArray(ssid, sizeof(ssid) - 1);
  server.arg("p").toCharArray(password, sizeof(password) - 1);
  server.sendHeader("Location", "wifi", true);
  server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  server.sendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  server.sendHeader("Expires", "-1");
  server.send(302, "text/plain", "");    // Empty content inhibits Content-length header so we have to close the socket ourselves.
  server.client().stop(); // Stop is needed because we sent no content length
  saveCredentials();
  connect = strlen(ssid) > 0; // Request WLAN connect with new credentials if there is a SSID
}

void handleNotFound() {
  if (captivePortal()) { // If caprive portal redirect instead of displaying the error page.
    return;
  }
  String message = F("File Not Found\n\n");
  message += F("URI: ");
  message += server.uri();
  message += F("\nMethod: ");
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += F("\nArguments: ");
  message += server.args();
  message += F("\n");

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
    message += String(F(" ")) + server.argName(i) + F(": ") + server.arg(i) + F("\n");
  }
  server.sendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  server.sendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  server.sendHeader("Expires", "-1");
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
}

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Configuring access point...");
  /* You can remove the password parameter if you want the AP to be open. */
  WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, netMsk);
  WiFi.softAP(softAP_ssid, softAP_password);
  delay(500); // Without delay I've seen the IP address blank
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());

  /* Setup the DNS server redirecting all the domains to the apIP */
  dnsServer.setErrorReplyCode(DNSReplyCode::NoError);
  dnsServer.start(DNS_PORT, "*", apIP);

  /* Setup web pages: root, wifi config pages, SO captive portal detectors and not found. */
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.on("/wifi", handleWifi);
  server.on("/wifisave", handleWifiSave);
  server.on("/generate_204", handleRoot);  //Android captive portal. Maybe not needed. Might be handled by notFound handler.
  server.on("/fwlink", handleRoot);  //Microsoft captive portal. Maybe not needed. Might be handled by notFound handler.
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  server.begin(); // Web server start
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
  loadCredentials(); // Load WLAN credentials from network
  connect = strlen(ssid) > 0; // Request WLAN connect if there is a SSID
}

void connectWifi() {
  Serial.println("Connecting as wifi client...");
  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  int connRes = WiFi.waitForConnectResult();
  Serial.print("connRes: ");
  Serial.println(connRes);
}

void loop() {
  if (connect) {
    Serial.println("Connect requested");
    connect = false;
    connectWifi();
    lastConnectTry = millis();
  }
  {
    unsigned int s = WiFi.status();
    if (s == 0 && millis() > (lastConnectTry + 60000)) {
      /* If WLAN disconnected and idle try to connect */
      /* Don't set retry time too low as retry interfere the softAP operation */
      connect = true;
    }
    if (status != s) { // WLAN status change
      Serial.print("Status: ");
      Serial.println(s);
      status = s;
      if (s == WL_CONNECTED) {
        /* Just connected to WLAN */
        Serial.println("");
        Serial.print("Connected to ");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        Serial.print("IP address: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

        // Setup MDNS responder
        if (!MDNS.begin(myHostname)) {
          Serial.println("Error setting up MDNS responder!");
        } else {
          Serial.println("mDNS responder started");
          // Add service to MDNS-SD
          MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);
        }
      } else if (s == WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL) {
        WiFi.disconnect();
      }
    }
    if (s == WL_CONNECTED) {
      MDNS.update();
    }
  }
  // Do work:
  //DNS
  dnsServer.processNextRequest();
  //HTTP
  server.handleClient();
}
```

---

[image: Example]

Comment: Such a simple yet brilliant idea!

Comment: It's great, but, it just works on my windows pc? :(   didn't work in my android :(

Comment: Wait! It's working nowww!!! GREATT!! You didn't say that we have to write "blablabla.com" instead of just random type "rat" or "asdjrgo" which will direct us to google search. (in short, don't test it by using url bar search engine feature). THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

The key is not only to use 8.8.8.8 for DNS address, but also adding a handler for the NotFound case. I know it's included in the question code, but I found it's mandatory for android auto-detect captive portal

When providing HTTP server you generally have two options:

1. Using WebServer class and set handlers for roots. The parsing and handling of HTTP header is done by the library.
2. Use WifiServer and receive the HTTP message with header included and handler everything by your own.

If you are doing number 1 and pretend using by connecting with an Android device I suggest adding a handler for the error case showing the captive portal:

```
server.onNotFound(handleRoot);
```

I noticed that for Android 10, to properly detect the captive portal and make the phone to show "Touch to log in the network" message is necesary. If not you must navigate to any HTTP address and let the DNS do the job for you (not HTTPS).

EDIT: In fact without using 8.8.8.8 nor 8.8.4.4 (i.e. using 192.168.0.1) it works for me. But I must include the handler for the error (onNotFound)